# iis 7.5 ipSecurity denyAction=NotFound causes 500 error instead of 404

Tags: security, configuration, iis-7.5

I'm restricting access to certain folders in an IIS 7.5 web application based on IP address. Here is a segment from applicationHost.config:

```
<ipSecurity allowUnlisted="false">
     <add ipAddress="172.16.0.0" subnetMask="255.255.0.0" allowed="true" />
</ipSecurity>
```

This returns a 403 Forbidden page and works as expected. But, I want it to return 404 Not Found instead. When I try the following code, however, I instead get a 500 error:

```
<ipSecurity allowUnlisted="false" denyAction="NotFound">
     <add ipAddress="172.16.0.0" subnetMask="255.255.0.0" allowed="true" />
</ipSecurity>
```

I've searched on Google but have found no answer.

Answer (score 0):

`denyAction` feature was introduced in IIS 8.0; you're using an older version so it will always return HTTP error code 500.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/security/ipsecurity/

Nevertheless, I'm using 8.5 and still finding that it doesn't function and a 500 is always returned.

Comment: For denyAction to work on IIS; the server needs to allow the delegation of that setting to the individual sites.  At the top level of IIS server, select "Feature Delegation".

Answer (score 0):

For `denyAction` to work on IIS version 8.0+; the server needs to allow the delegation of that setting to the individual sites.  At the top level of IIS server, select "Feature Delegation".

Make sure the *IP Address and Domain Restrictions* is set to *Read/Write*.
[image]